# How to ignore mouse activity until function completes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the following code to slide out a div on a mouse-over, wait a couple of seconds and slide the div back.

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {$("#divider").mouseover(function () 
        {$("#slider").show("slide", {direction: "left"}, 1000).pause(2000).hide("slide", {direction: "left"}, 1000);}
    );}
);
```

I'm sure this is simple, but I have limited Javascript/jQuery knowledge. How do I make it so any mouse activity on the trigger is ignored until the animation completes? Right now, if while the div is open you mouse over the trigger area it "remembers" and plays the animation for as many times as you've moved the pointer through the trigger area. [Page](http://www.peninou.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bind and unbind and rebind instead use a flag to decide if you should care about the event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#divider").mouseover(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.data('nomouse')) return;
        $this.data('nomouse',true);
        $("#slider")
        .show("slide", {direction: "left"}, 1000)
        .pause(2000)
        .hide("slide", {direction: "left"}, 1000, function() {
            $this.data('nomouse',false);
        });
    });
});
```

Binding and unbinding was of one  [Paul Irish's](http://paulirish.com/) jQuery Anti-Patterns in the [yayQuery podcast](http://yayquery.com/)

Comment: I agree completely with this answer, +1. My binding/unbinding isn't nearly as snazzy. Thanks for the links!

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest removing the event from your divider until the animation is finished, than using the hide callback function to add that event handler back in.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function divider_mouseover() {
        $('#divider').unbind('mouseover');

        $("#slider")
           .show("slide", {direction: "left"}, 1000)
           .pause(2000)
           .hide("slide", {direction: "left"}, 1000, function() {
               $("#divider").mouseover(divider_mouseover);
           });
    };

    $("#divider").mouseover(divider_mouseover);
};
```

Comment: I think I understand what you've done, but it's not working because the initial event isn't firing so mousing over doesn't trigger the first slide.

Comment: Nasty don't bind and unbind and rebind.  Use a flag.  Binding and unbinding adds extra overhead and can slow things down.

Answer (score 0):

Swizzle out the event handler (not sure if this works, but something along these lines):

```
var omo = function() {
    {$("#divider").mouseover(function () {});}
    slide();
}

var slide = function() {
    {$("#slider").show("slide", {direction: "left"}, 1000)
                 .pause(2000)
                 .hide("slide", {direction: "left"}, 1000);
    }
    {$("#divider").mouseover(omo);}
}

$(document).ready(function()
    {$("#divider").mouseover(omo);}
);
```

Comment: Same as above. The initial mouse-over doesn't seem to trigger, so it does nothing.